# How to compare same keys values from two different dict

Tags: python

Trying to compare same keys values from two different dict, If second dict value is bigger than first dict value then output should show different keys values only.

```
Example:
first={'a': '1000', 'b': '2000', 'c': '3000'}
second={'a': '1000', 'b': '3000', 'c': '5000'}
new dict output should be {'b': '3000', 'c': '5000'}
```

how to do this comperison

Comment: did you try to write some code to do it? show it, so we can help.

Comment: non of codes last few hours I tried did work

Answer (score 2):

Using a dict comprehension

**Ex:**

```
first={'a': '1000', 'b': '2000', 'c': '3000'}
second={'a': '1000', 'b': '3000', 'c': '5000'}
print(dict((k, second[k])for k in second if second[k] > first[k]))
```

**Output:**

```
{'c': '5000', 'b': '3000'}
```

Comment: That's not a dict comprehension. :) It's a `dict` constructed from a generator expression.

Comment: Rakesh if instead of not just bigger , to get same keys values that are bigger by 3% than first dict values, do you know how to do that ?

Comment: @J87 Please accept ans if it solved your problem. Thanks